# Print paragraphs from text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a twitter bot that tweets from a text file but can't figure out how to paragraphs. I want it to be able to print text separately from each line. Like this:

```
example tweet
and some text to accompany it

another example tweet
with some more text
```

Here is my supporting code. Note this is only setup for reading/tweeting each individual line.

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep
from credentials import*

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

my_file = open('quotes.txt')
file_lines = my_file.readlines()
my_file.close()

# Tweet a line every hour
def tweet():
for line in file_lines:
    try:
         print(line)
         if line != '\n':
             api.update_status(line)
             sleep(3600)
         else:
            pass
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
        sleep(2)

tweet()
```

Comment: So your question is.... ?

Comment: your `else` block is unnecessary btw.

Comment: @barny How would I go about tweeting multiple lines at a time?

Comment: is it your problem, that it posts one line per tweet instead of posting many lines in one tweet from file up to a newline? if so, try to concatenate lines like `'\n'.join([line1, line2])` and then post those joined lines at once.

Comment: @adamczi for each tweet, i want it to print each line but break at a blank line. how could i implement that?

Comment: does blank line's length is zero?

Comment: @lz975545 then join lines with a `\n` until you find an empty line. Then post this comibnation of lines at once, and continue with following lines.